# Shortcut key to make my macbook sleep?

Tags: sleep-wake, macos

Is there a shortcut key to make a macbook sleep?  Sometimes I want to save time and just use the shortcut key to put it to sleep.

Comment: For others coming from google with a non-apple keyboard looking for a way to turn off the screen somehow, a quick way is **hot corners**.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

## Putting your computer to sleep

[image]

Above is how to sleep your computer when it's on and logged in.

The keyboard shortcut is: <kbd>ALT/OPT</kbd> + <kbd>CMD</kbd> + <kbd>Eject</kbd>
(i.e., <kbd>⌥</kbd> + <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>⏏</kbd>).

## Putting your display to sleep

[image]

Above is the keyboard shortcut for putting your *display* to sleep. The computer itself will not go to sleep, only the display will power off.

The keyboard shortcut is: <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Eject</kbd> 
(i.e. <kbd>⇧</kbd> + <kbd>⌃</kbd> + <kbd>⏏</kbd>).

---

#### Note: Computers that lack the Eject key

For computers that lack the <kbd>⏏</kbd> key – e.g. MacBooks – the Power key (<kbd>⌽</kbd>) can be used instead.

Also, it's possible to hold down the Power key for 1.5 seconds and then select from a menu if you want to *Sleep*, *Restart* or *Power off*. You can also access the menu immediately by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>⌽</kbd>.

Comment: This shortcut only puts your displays to sleep. The correct shortcut for putting your mac to sleep is Cmd+Option+Eject, as pointed out by Matthieu Riegler. See also http://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201247

Comment: The shortcut is not shown on the Apple menu anymore.

Comment: @Stan I have now edited the answer so that it's correct.

Comment: Does not work on touch-bar enabled MacBooks with OS Mojave.

Comment: `Ctrl+Shift+Power` worked for me on Macbook Pro mid 2014

Comment: Can I put the pc to sleep as I can in Windows or Linux? It seems that only the display will turn black in sleep mode on a Mac.

Answer (score 17):

Supposing you're using an Apple Keyboard: <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Option</kbd>+<kbd>Eject</kbd>

Answer (score 4):

Under Mavericks, pressing the power button puts your Mac to sleep. This behavior [changed](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT5869) from previous versions of OS X when this button toggled the shut-down/sleep/restart menu. You can access this menu by pressing the button a little longer or pressing `ctrl + power button`.

Answer (score 4):

I like the CTRL EJECT as it brings up a dialog allowing you to sleep, restart or shutdown, like so:

Pressing ENTER shuts down
Pressing R restarts
Pressing S sleeps
ESC cancels

BTW if you have a PC keyboard with no EJECT key, use F12

Answer (score 3):

If you have a keyboard with no eject or power key, you can use a [private.xml](http://pqrs.org/macosx/keyremap4macbook/xml.html.en) like this with KeyRemap4MacBook:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root>
  <item>
    <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::S, VK_CONTROL | VK_OPTION | VK_COMMAND | ModifierFlag::NONE, KeyCode::VK_CONSUMERKEY_EJECT, ModifierFlag::OPTION_L | ModifierFlag::COMMAND_L</autogen>
    <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::D, VK_CONTROL | VK_OPTION | VK_COMMAND | ModifierFlag::NONE, KeyCode::VK_CONSUMERKEY_EJECT, ModifierFlag::CONTROL_L | ModifierFlag::SHIFT_L</autogen>
    <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::R, VK_CONTROL | VK_OPTION | VK_COMMAND | ModifierFlag::NONE, KeyCode::VK_CONSUMERKEY_EJECT, ModifierFlag::CONTROL_L | ModifierFlag::COMMAND_L</autogen>
  </item>
</root>
```

Option-command-eject puts the Mac to sleep, control-shift-eject puts displays to sleep, and control-command-eject restarts the Mac.

Comment: my menu missing mapping for "Sleep" - Q pls where can I put this #xml ?

Comment: KeyRemap4MacBook was renamed to Karabiner, which has been obsoleted in favor of Karabiner-Elements: https://karabiner-elements.pqrs.org/